# View Sqlite Database in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: sqlite, xamarin.ios

I am using xamarin studio with xcode to create a ipad application
I have created database and table using sqlite.
Questions is, how do I view all the data I have input in the table and database.

Thanks for any answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQLite Browser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/) will help you to add/update/delete and query data in tables, and also view data.

Ideally you should save the database file in

```
Path.Combine (Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "DBName.db");
```

This will be at following path > 
/users/[name]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[version]/Applications/**SomeNumberedApp**/Documents/DBName.db

where **SomeNumberedApp** is a folder which will contain:

1. Documents folder
2. Application file for your app (named after your app)
3. Library folder
4. tmp folder

You would find your database in Documents folder.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/) is a Firefox plugin that allows you to manage SQLite databases.

Comment: Where should the file usually be ?
I tried Try /users/[name]/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/[version]/Applications. 
But i can't find any

Comment: Depending on where you stored it, it should be there - each application installed in the simulator will have a GUID folder.  Inside that folder will be the app bundle, as well as folders for Library, Documents, etc